# How do you log messages onto console in Robotframework? Is there any keyword?

Tags: robotframework

How can i log messages onto console in Robot framework, when I use the log keyword, it gets logged onto the report file. Please advice.

Answer (score 38):

There are two ways to do it.

- The [BuiltIn](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html) library has a keyword named [Log to console](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log%20To%20Console)
- You can use the [Log](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log) keyword and include the argument `console=True`.

```
Log             using the Log keyword  console=True
Log to console  using the 'log to console' keyword
```

Both will log the given string to the console, but using `Log` also causes the message to appear in the generated log.

[image: screenshot of log.html]